# I want the main image to load before the thumbnails of previous and next images on a album photo page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So, basically I want to load the thumbnails(of other images) with least priority, so that the user experience is good in viewing the main image.

I want to load the normal image and the rest of the page, and then when it is all done, the thumbnails can take their time to load the thumbnails.

How can this be achieved ? A simple solution is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the urls of the thumbnails then set the src attribute of the image tag on document.Ready function
or to just show the perception, you can hide the thumbanails till document.ready and make them visible at the end of document.ready function

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no simple solution.

You can't use JavaScript because your users may have scripting disabled and therefore wouldn't be able to see the images at all.

You could put all of the images in a single file and treat them like [sprites](http://w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).  This way they'll all load at the same time...although it isn't a very good solution tbh.

At the very least make sure to set the width and height of your images so your page layout wont change as they're loading.